# Conditional select rows and columns in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: dataframe

I have a data frame

```
>>> df
    name  score
0    tom    1.1
1   ally    5.2
2  homer   11.0
```

And I use

```
x = df[df.name == 'tom'].score
```

to get the score for the name 'tom'.
I want x to be a numerical value so it can do all sorts of mathematical calculations with other values I obtain from a separate dataframe. And I find it a bit bothering that when I try this

```
df[df.name == 'tom'].score * df[df.name == 'homer'].score
```

the output becomes

```
0   NaN
2   NaN
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

I have trouble with this, any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The return value of the `df[]` selector is a Series and multiplication will work on index aligned values only. You probably are looking for something like this: `df[df.name == 'tom'].score.values[0] * df[df.name == 'homer'].score.values[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am in a transition from R to python now and fumbling through the panda's dataframe. This little nugget really bothers me.